# How can I update specific React Components in a grid without updating every component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization, react-usememo

I am creating a grid of HTML elements which each correspond to a 'Node' react component and are held within a parent 'Visualiser' react component. Code is seen below.

A 2D array of objects holding each Node's data is created with useState in the Visualiser parent component. Data about a specific Node in this list is updated one at a time when a Node child component is clicked on using callback functions given to the child as props. Node data could also change if the user is currently holding their mouse down and hovers over the Node, which is implementated using a simple mousePressed useState. This is used to create a painting like effect on the grid, but becomes very laggy.

I understand that React will re-render every Node component whenever gridData is updated, because even though only one object out of the gridData has changed, React sees this as the entire gridData changing.

I have tried changing the Node child component to be a React.memo HOC, and then using the useCallback hook on my three mouse click methods to make sure that React will memoize the data props it is given and the function callbacks. I have also tried manually changing the React.memo isEquals comparison to shallow compare only the nodeData given.

Both of these methods have resulted in only the Nodes I clicked to update (kind of), but I can no longer drag to 'paint' in many Nodes at a time, and there is also weird behaviour where mouse click callbacks no longer properly change the state of gridData or mousePressed, which makes me think that there is a much more proper way to do this.

I know that I need to use react's memoization somewhere to improve perfomance, I just don't know how or where. Any help would be really appreciated!!

Visualiser Component Code:

```
export default Visualiser = () => {

const [gridData, updateGridData] = React.useState(createGridData())
const [mousePressed, updateMousePressed] = React.useState(false)

// Toggles the 'wall' property for a Node at row, col
const placeWallInGrid = (row, col) => {
    const newGrid = [...gridData]
    const wallNode = newGrid[row][col]
    const newNode = {
        ...wallNode, isWall: !wallNode.isWall,
    }
    newGrid[row][col] = newNode
    return newGrid
}

// Possible useCallback functions that are called in child <Node /> components
const handleMouseDown = (row, col) => {
    updateGridData(placeWallInGrid(row, col))
    updateMousePressed(true)
}

const handleMouseEnter = (row, col) => {
    if (mousePressed) {
        updateGridData(placeWallInGrid(row, col))
    }
}

const handleMouseUp = () => {
    updateMousePressed(false)
}

// Main render - possible useMemo?
return (
    <div className="grid">
        {gridData.map((rowData, rowIndex) => {
            return (
                <div key={rowIndex}>
                    {rowData.map((node, colIndex) => {
                        return (
                            <Node 
                            key={nodeIndex} 
                            nodeData={node}
                            onMouseDown={() => {handleMouseDown(rowIndex, colIndex)}}
                            onMouseEnter={() => {handleMouseEnter(rowIndex, colIndex)}}
                            onMouseUp={() => {handleMouseUp()}}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>

)
}
```

Creation of 2D node data array:

```
const createNode = (row, col) => {
    return ({
        row,
        col,
        isWall: false,
    })
}

const createGridData = () => {
    const grid = []
    for (let row = 0; row < Constants.NUM_ROWS; row++) {
        const currentRow = []
        for (let col = 0; col < Constants.NUM_COLS; col++) {
            currentRow.push(createNode(row, col))
        }
        grid.push(currentRow)
    }
    return grid
}
```

Comment: You need to use another key identifier instead of index e.g item id or uuid, and memorize that using ```React.useMemo```. And passing prop functions with ```useCallBack```.